# Why is my DataTable added to my DataSet temporarily?

Tags: datatable, dataset

I am trying to add a DataTable to an existing DataSet(already had 6 DataTables) through coding. It adds it successfully, but temporarily. When I close the window and re-execute, the newly added DataTable is not in the DataSet anymore. How can I make this addition PERMANENT? My DataSet is called Earth this is what I did:

Earth er = new Earth();

DataTable tb = new DataTable(tabname1);

tb.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(float));

tb.Columns.Add("c2", typeof(float));

tb.Columns.Add("c3", typeof(float));

tb.Rows.Add(25, 23, 23);

er.Tables.Add(tb);

Answer (score 0):

Is Earth a typed DataSet?  If so you need to edit the definition of that typed dataset by editing the XSD file that defines it.